# how to call function from Switch

Tags: dart, flutter

With the default `Flutter` app created in `Android Studio`, I tried to test the [Switch](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Switch/Switch.html), so I added the below code:

```
new Switch(value: true, onChanged: (bool newValue) {
  setState(() {
    _incrementCounter();  // executed only if the value is true
  });
},),
```

The `incrementCounter` function is:

```
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
```

The issue I've is that the `incrementCounter` function is called and executed once the `Switch` value is switched back to `false`, while what I expect is the `incrementCounter` function should be called every time the switch is switched, i.e. regardless the new value is true or false!

Comment: If you call `_incrementCounter()` inside `setState(...)` then `_incrementCounter()` doesn't need to call `setState()` again. One of these 2 `setState` is redundant.

Comment: When you add `(bool newValue) { /* add this */ print('newValue: $newValue'); ...` what does it print when you toggle the switch?

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer for the note, the behavior still the same.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it prints `newValue: false` only once the switch is false, nothing printed once it is true

Comment: Sounds like the opposite of what you explained in the question above.

Comment: Sorry @GünterZöchbauer I fixed it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @aziza said the problem is :

> You are not switching the value.

So this should work

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _value=false;
  var inc=0;
  onchange(bool value){
    setState((){
     inc++;
     _value=value;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body : new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Switch(value: _value, onChanged: (bool value)=>onchange(value)),
        new Center(child: new Text("value ${inc}"),)
      ],)
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The Android emulator have a recording option and from there you can export it to GIF

Answer (score 1):

You are not switching the value.

The error is basically in your code in this line:

```
value: true
```

You can have a class level boolean to handle this.

Example:

```
//State level class

bool switchValue = false;
  _dummyMethod(){
    print (this.switchValue);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Switch(
          onChanged: (newValue){
            setState((){
              this.switchValue = newValue;
            });
            _dummyMethod();
          },
         value: switchValue,)
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have added an example, basically what you needed is to alternate the 
 value property between true and false instead of having it equals to true all the time

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  var _value=false;
  double _bodyHeight=0.0;

  void onchange(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
      this._bodyHeight = (value == true) ? 400.0 : 0.0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[500],
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Card(
              child: new Container(
                height: 50.0,
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text("Select me pls"),
                    new Switch(value: _value, onChanged: (bool value) => onchange(value)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Card(
              child: new AnimatedContainer(
                child: new ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                      new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                      title: new TextField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Name",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.phone),
                      title: new TextField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Phone",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.email),
                      title: new TextField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Email",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Divider(
                      height: 1.0,
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.label),
                      title: const Text('Nick'),
                      subtitle: const Text('None'),
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.today),
                      title: const Text('Birthday'),
                      subtitle: const Text('February 20, 1980'),
                    ),
                      new ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.group),
                        title: const Text('Contact group'),
                        subtitle: const Text('Not specified'),
                      ),
                      new ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                        title: new TextField(
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Name",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      new ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.phone),
                        title: new TextField(
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Phone",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      new ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.email),
                        title: new TextField(
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Email",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Divider(
                        height: 1.0,
                      ),
                      new ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.label),
                        title: const Text('Nick'),
                        subtitle: const Text('None'),
                      ),
                      new ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.today),
                        title: const Text('Birthday'),
                        subtitle: const Text('February 20, 1980'),
                      ),
                      new ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.group),
                        title: const Text('Contact group'),
                        subtitle: const Text('Not specified'),
                      )
                  ],
                ),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                height: _bodyHeight,
                // color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```